# How can I extract an INT from the following ROOM Database query result?

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I am running the following valid Room SQL query in order to find the next available ID for the auto incremented `payee` column, and want to capture the result from it as an Integer. The below code does just that, but it only works when stepping through with breakpoints, and NOT when normally executing:

```
@Query("SELECT seq FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name = 'payee'")
int getNextAutoIncrementPayeeID();
```

The following repository method calls the above Dao method:

```
 public void getNextAutoIncrementPayeeID(OnValueListener listener) {

    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Call the listener callback
            listener.onValue(db.payeeDao().getNextAutoIncrementPayeeID());
        }
    });

}
```

The interface used:

```
public interface OnValueListener {

    public void onValue(int value);

}
```

Now the result of `value` is assigned to a global variable `payeeId` but, that only works when running the code with breakpoints:

```
 repository.getNextAutoIncrementPayeeID(new OnValueListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValue(int value) {
            // use "value" which is returned from Room

            payeeId = value;

        }
    });
```

Comment: have you tried just retrieving seq instead of an array of ints `"SELECT seq FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name = 'payee'"`  should return `int` or `long`

Answer (score 0):

```
final int[] result = {0};
int test = result[0];
return test;
```

This is called in main thread, so it returns 0 before the background thread run by `db.payeeDao().getNextAutoIncrementPayeeID()` is up.

So, you need to wait until the query `db.payeeDao().getNextAutoIncrementPayeeID();` finished and returned a result, but how much you can wait?

Well, in this case you can use a listener and trigger its callback whenever a value returned from Room database.

Create an interface that has a callback that accepts an int

```
interface OnValueListener {
    public void onValue(int value);
}
```

Pass an instance of the interface to the Repository query

```
 public void getNextAutoIncrementPayeeID(OnValueListener listener) {

    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Call the listener callback
            listener.onValue(db.payeeDao().getNextAutoIncrementPayeeID());
        }
    });

}
```

And implement the `OnValueListener` instance in activity/fragment of the call:

```
getNextAutoIncrementPayeeID(new OnValueListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValue(int value) {
        // use "value" which is returned from Room
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Zain... this is probably what I need, greatly appreciate it. How can I pass the int all the way through and access  it as a variable during the final activity/fragment call?

Comment: You need to create similar methods all the way down to the activity that accepts an `OnValueListener`  object as a parameter, and eventually in activity/fragment implement this instance like I did .. If that solved the problem thanks to accept the answer

Comment: Thank you @Zain, it works and pulls a value when I step through the code using breakpoints, but whenever I execute it without breakpoints, it never pulls a value. I cannot figure out why, it's the same code... does it have something to do with threads or timing somehow?

Comment: Can you update the question with the current code

Comment: I've updated the code @Zain... any further advice would be appreciated, this is driving me nuts.

Comment: @TDawg do you call `repository.getNextAutoIncrementPayeeID` in activity? Also are you sure that values in database are not 0? .. The `onValue()` won't get called unless the there is a value returned back from database

Comment: Yes I do call that from an Activity @Zain. Just now I witnessed the variable return 0  WITH breakpoints enabled so it's got nothing to do with that. So it's not always returning a result from the database like you suspected, even though the query always returns a result when run by itself. Any thoughts on why that might be?